# Selenium | How to iterate | TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, iterable

Please find the attached screenshot below i want to fetch the rows i.e all tweets rows.
i struggling to how to iterate and fetch all rows.

[image]

Below code i have tried.

```
driver.get("https://www.trackmyhashtag.com/")

form = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='container']")
usrinput = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/header/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/input')
usrinput.clear()
usrinput.send_keys("india")

loginbt = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/header/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/button')
loginbt.click()
time.sleep(5)

ad = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/button')
ad.click()
time.sleep(5)

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/aside/nav/div/ul/li[2]/a')
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
actions.click().perform()
time.sleep(5)

ad=wait.until(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/button'))

row = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div/div/div/div[2]/div')

for i in row:
    i.get_attribute('td')
    print(i)

print("inside it")
```

Comment: Try this xPath `//table[@id='tweets_table']//tr` for `row` and `row = driver.find_elements_by_xpath`

Comment: tried ! no luck. same error TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable

Comment: Try the updated.. You need to use find elements

Comment: @pkk have you tried my answer? It was a typo there, already fixed it.

Comment: yes ! but it is giving some exception. Please find comment in your answer.

Comment: @pkk is my solution working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the tweets rows you can use this

```py
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[@role='row' and(@class)]")
```

Now to get, for example, the tweets names you can do this:

```py
actions = ActionChains(driver)

rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[@role='row' and(@class)]")
for i in range(1,len(rows)+1):
    row = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//tr[@role='row' and(@class)])[" + str(i) + "]")
    actions.move_to_element(row).perform()
    time.sleep(1)
    row = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//tr[@role='row' and(@class)])[" + str(i) + "]")
    name = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='tweet-name']").text
    content = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[2]").text
    date = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[2]").text
    impressions = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[6]").text
```

To use `actions` you will need to import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression .////div[@class='tweet-name'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string './///div[@class='tweet-name']' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: ups.. sory. fixed the typo

Comment: it is printing only first two names and others printing it blank.

Comment: OK, I added finding each row separately and scrolling to it before getting the content. I hope now it will work better

Comment: working. can you please advise that how should i print tweet content, impression ,date fields also as it don't have any specific class name as you are using to fetch name as   tweet-name

Comment: OK, I added the date, content etc.

Comment: @Prophet :  are you sure that it is working ? cause with your code I am getting stale element reference

Comment: Not totally sure. I have added `row = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//tr[@role='row' and(@class)])[" + str(i) + "]")` after scrolling the element into the view again. Hope this will make it better.

Comment: You are welcome! Do you see `stale element reference` problems mentioned by cruisepandey?

Comment: No i didn't find any issues working fine for me.

Comment: Great! Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

This exception :

### TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable

is cause you should use `find_elements` which returns a list, and can be iterable, not `find_element` which returns a single web element.

**Code :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2})
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_settings.cookies": 2})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = driver_path, options = options)
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get("https://www.trackmyhashtag.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

actions = ActionChains(driver)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "search_keyword"))).send_keys("India", Keys.RETURN)

def close_up():
    time.sleep(1)
    actions.move_to_element(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-dismiss='modal']"))))
    button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-dismiss='modal']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
    time.sleep(1)

def check_model_winodows():
    try:
        if len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "(//button[@data-dismiss='modal'])[1]")) >0:
            print("Pop up is visible")
            close_up()
        else:
            print("Pop up is not visible")
    except:
        print("Something went wrong")
        pass

check_model_winodows()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[onclick*='preview-tweets']"))).click()
check_model_winodows()
total_number_of_tweet_row = len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//tbody/tr"))
print(total_number_of_tweet_row)

j = 0
    for i in range(total_number_of_tweet_row):
        check_model_winodows()
        elems = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//tbody/tr")
        time.sleep(1)
        final_ele = elems[j].find_element_by_xpath(".//td[2]")
        print("code worked till here")
        print(final_ele.text)
        j = j + 1
        check_model_winodows()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `find_elements_by_xpath` instead of `find_element_by_xpath`

```
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id='tweets_table']//tr//td')

for row in rows:
    print(row.text)
```

Comment: It is working but is printing only 2 tweets and printing blank spaces after it. I have tried print(row.text) instead of print(row)

Comment: can you add the `HTML` under `<tr>` tage

Comment: sorry i didnt get it ? where should i put it ?

Comment: Can you try now?

Comment: Are you trying to print user name and tweet content? or only tweet content?

Comment: everthing comes under that row. this solution also printing only first two contents and others  showing blank  spaces .

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.trackmyhashtag.com/")

form = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='container']")
usrinput = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/header/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/input')
usrinput.clear()
usrinput.send_keys("india")

loginbt = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/header/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/button')
loginbt.click()

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/aside/nav/div/ul/li[2]/a')
actions = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
actions.click().perform()

rows = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'tbody > tr')))

for row in rows:
    tds = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')
    if len(tds) > 0:
        for td in tds:
            print(td.text.strip())
                
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
Waheed
@Waheedullahsha
RT @News18Urdu: صدر جمعیۃ علما ہند مولانا ارشدمدنی نے آج مظفر نگر فساد میں بے گھر ہوئ...
25 Aug 2021
06:29:52 PM
2
376

Abhijeet D. Sangle
@ADSangl3
RT @sarbanandsonwal: Tomorrow, we will be signing an agreement with Hooghly Cochin Shipyard Limited for Ship Repair Facility (Slipway) at P?...
25 Aug 2021
06:29:52 PM
31
304

ck@chandan
@Ck__ChaNDaN
78 at Headingley is #TeamIndia's 9th lowest Test total of all-time, eight months after recording their lowest ever score of 36 in Australia....
25 Aug 2021
06:29:52 PM
0
35

Vinod
@VinodpalP
RT @vivekagnihotri: 100% lobbying for vegan brands, almond milk etc. They just want @Amul_Coop to shut down. India is the largest milk prod?...
25 Aug 2021
06:29:51 PM
297
378

Akash Dwivedi
@akashdwivedi97
RT @narendramodi: Chaired the 37th PRAGATI session during which projects with over Rs. 1,26,000 crore across 14 states were reviewed. We al?...
25 Aug 2021
06:29:51 PM
2429
2501

raj skf
@SkfRaj
RT @HEAD__OF__TABLE: Swimming could have been an alternative career for Salman. He was a swimming champion at school and even tipped to rep?...
25 Aug 2021
06:29:51 PM
2
3

.....Arron..... 
@arron_sharma
RT @noconversion: India का कुछ नहीं हो सकता
25 Aug 2021
06:29:51 PM
908
956

JS Bits
@js_bits
RT @richardkimphd: 5 Things India Should Learn from The US's #AI and ML Policy? 2021-08-24T14:30:35Z #NaturalLanguageProcessing #Matplotli?...
25 Aug 2021
06:29:50 PM
3
3132

Naveen Dass
@NaveenD05684789
RT @Lalitamanikpur1: "TOBACCO IS THE BIGGEST HINDRANCE IN PATH OF BHAKTI" Visit our YouTube Channel: Sant Rampal Ji Maharaj #GodMorningWedn?...
25 Aug 2021
06:29:50 PM
24
497

Nagendra Pathak ( ADV )
@nagendrapathak
RT @somnath456: @Somnath08976511 @nm0565593 @Krishna9936170 @Ashokaaa5 @opsethi @harbanssaini19 @yashwant9617612 @VijaySi51 @skn_337 @MrsMe?...
25 Aug 2021
06:29:50 PM
2
1513

Sanjeeb Patra
@sanjeeb603148
RT @narendramodi: Best of luck India! I am sure our #Paralympics contingent will give their best and inspire others.
25 Aug 2021
06:29:50 PM
10768
10779

মন্নু ঝা
@man123kar
Mother tongue is one of the unique identity of the people. Union of India's beautiful linguistic diversity. No one has the right to impose t...
25 Aug 2021
06:29:49 PM
0
15

Khavatari
@Hrolf_Kraki
RT @alomgc14: Alonso en Spa 2013  [1/3] Salidón en un circuito difícil donde es difícil hacerlas. Se funde al Force India, a los...
25 Aug 2021
06:29:49 PM
12
765

Wisal Muhammad Khan
@IbneDost
RT @CynthiaDRitchie: India's own Congress stating Modi ji could not care less about the people's progress or prosperity. Their hashtag: #I?...
25 Aug 2021
06:29:49 PM
7
401

Premnath Bhardwaj
@PremnathBhardw8
A powerful jihadi channel of India.
25 Aug 2021
06:29:49 PM
0
117

Zoe
@mysticlionheart
RT @GabbbarSingh: Vikram Rathore is India's batting choke.
25 Aug 2021
06:29:49 PM
2
47

.
@Arv_Ga
RT @Kishlaysharma: No matter what India's fate tomorrow . I will always be able to say that I was NOT a part of this destruction &amp; I wa...
25 Aug 2021
06:29:49 PM
9
630

P-A
@BigDreamBigShot
RT @FreedomIsrael_: One of these countries prescribes #VACCINES, the other prescribes #IVERMECTIN Retweet if you know which is which. Clu?...
25 Aug 2021
06:29:48 PM
298
332

Larry Wu
@lwu0303
@_IndianPatriot @_ChachaChaudhry @PomPomSlappy @Anna30253409 @BasavaprasadNa8 @globaltimesnews Police brutality in india
25 Aug 2021
06:29:48 PM
0
74

India Covid Vaccine Availability
@india_vac
MUMBAI: 79933 slots found for age 18+! Aug 25, 2021: 440 slots found in pincode 400026 at 3 centers Aug 25, 2021: 38 slots found in pincode ...
25 Aug 2021
06:29:48 PM
0
453
```